# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Text'

Tags: typescript, cypress

Moving from `.js` to `typesript`. As I rename the file  `.js`  to `.ts` file with same code. It started throwing an error `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Text'.ts` over `then((value)` method.

Return type of  `getIDHome()`  is '`Text`'. I don't understand,   why  `then((value)` is not supporting to return type `Text` in `.ts` whereas it was works well on `.js` file.  Kindly help to resolve the `then` issue .

script      `../support/PageObject/Home.ts` :

```
getID(){ 
        cy.wait(3000)
        return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cy.getIDHome(Row, ID).then((value)=>{
            Cypress.env('ID', value.toString());
            cy.log(Cypress.env('ID')+' :: adding ID  in globale varibale ')
            resolve(value.toString());
            })
        })
        }
```

[image]

Custome command `../support/commands.js` :

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIDHome', (Row, ID) => {   
cy.get('[class^="'+Row+'"]').then($Container=>{
    const isID = $Container.find('[class^="'+ID+'"]', {timeout:2000}).get(0)
      cy.wrap(isID.innerText);Text


   })
```

import custom command  `../support/index.js` :

```
import './commands'
```

declare custom command `../support/index.ts` :

```
declare namespace Cypress{
    interface Chainable<Subject = any>{

        getHome( Row: String ,  ID: String):Text;
```

}
}

Comment: What type is Text ?

Comment: @Evert , Text is return type . In chaining function ` cy.getIDHome(Row, ID)`  return values as `Text`

Comment: If `getHome` (`getIDHome`?) has a `then` method, I would imagine it's quite likely that it returns a `Promise<Text>` rather than a `Text`. Are you sure that's not the case? Or is `Text` a `Promise` itself?

Comment: MOre specifically, what _is_ the `Text` type. I can see it's the return type, i can't see what it refers to. In your failing example it suggests that the `Text` should have a `.then()` function, so share the definition.

Comment: @Evert  ` declare namespace Cypress{   interface Chainable<Subject = any>{   getHome( Row: String ,  ID: String):Text;`  . It is already shared in declare custom command ../support/index.ts :

Comment: @user3302083, well either type for `Text` is wrong (it's missing a `then()` function which you are clearly calling), or getHome is does not return `Text`

Comment: But you still haven't shared the type of `Text`, you're just sharing the type of a function that returns `Text`. Where is `Text` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getHome` appears to be asynchronous because it operates on promises. But your function is not typed to return a promise (unless `Text` is defined to explicitly extend `Promise`).

Which means the function return type should be `Promise<Text>`.

---

Also your command doesn't return anything, or resolve any promise.

I'm guessing you want something more like this?

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIDHome', (Row, ID) => {   
  return cy.get('[class^="'+Row+'"]').then($Container=>{
    const isID = $Container.find('[class^="'+ID+'"]', {timeout:2000}).get(0)
    return cy.wrap(isID.innerText);
   })
}))
```